# Value of type 'Int' has no member 'rawValue'

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot get my app to build in iOS. I receive the following error in Xcode in the "SwiftFlutterPlugin.swift" file

Error:

self.tmpWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(baseWindowLevel! + 1.rawValue) Value of type 'Int' has no member 'rawValue'

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This

```
self.tmpWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(baseWindowLevel! + 1.rawValue)
```

should most likely be

```
self.tmpWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(baseWindowLevel! + 1)
```

i.e. get rid of the `.rawValue`. Usally only `enum`s have those.

Answer (score 0):

Your value of 1 is an Int, it has no additional properties.

I'm guessing it was supposed to be a value from an enum and that's where the .rawValue idea is coming from.

So for example if you had an enum:

```
public enum Weight: Int {
    case image = 1
    case audio = 10
    case video = 100
}
```

then in your code you could reference the values as:

```
let imageWeight: Weight = .image
let myValue = imageWeight.rawValue
```

so myValue's value and imageWeight's rawType would be both 1